# Error getting response stream (ReadDone1): ReceiveFailure

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webrequest

I'm developing a Android Application using Xamarin and after upgrading the Xamarin to it's latest version, the following exception is being thrown in my WebRequest:

> {System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (ReadDone1):
>   ReceiveFailure ---> System.IO.IOException: EndRead failure --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection reset by peer at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive (IAsyncResult result) [0x00000]
>   in :0  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead (IAsyncResult ar)
>   [0x00000] in :0 
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead (IAsyncResult ar) [0x00000]
>   in :0  at
>   Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.InternalReadCallback
>   (IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in :0 
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   [0x00000] in :0  at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory1[System.Net.WebResponse].InnerInvoke
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource1 tcs, System.Func
>
> 2 endMethod, IAsyncResult l) [0x00000] in :0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter
>   1[System.Net.WebResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in :0  at
>   Modulo.CICC.Chat.Core.ConnectionFactory.WebServices+d__32.MoveNext ()
>   [0x000db] in c:\Users\Raphael
>   Alvarenga\Documents\Projects\SESGE\Modulo.CICC.Chat\Modulo.CICC.Chat.Core\ConnectionFactory\WebServices.cs:205
>   }

Here is the code:

```
try
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);

    string data = "access_token=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(accessToken) + "&refresh_token=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(refreshToken);

    WebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url + "?" + data);

    myWebRequest.Method = method;
    myWebRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
    myWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    HttpWebResponse response = await myWebRequest.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse;

    string headerSetCookie = response.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
    response.Close();
    return headerSetCookie;    
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw e;
}
```

Any thoughts why it throws an exception?
Also posted the issue in Xamarin's Forum: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/32554/error-getting-response-stream-readdone1-receivefailure?new=1

Thanks in regards.

Comment: I am quite sure you've been hit by Mono's terrible htpps stack. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665010/httpclient-xamarin-android-mvvmcross for solutions